Unity Button ID is -1
I have a UI Document on a gameobject. while hovering on a UI button when i press mouse 4  on my logitech g502 it gives me an error. I did this by accident when i pressed mouse 4 instead of left clicking.


how would i fix this error so that if i press mouse 4 it ignores it or something?

This looks like an engine bug to report to Unity themselves.
